# How can we integrate Oracle database with Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, oracle11g, drupal-modules

How can we integrate Oracle database with Drupal 6.

Tried with Oracle driver but it not showing oracle database option at Installation time.

Need help to work Oracle database with Drupal 6

Comment: dry drupal 7 php pdo should take care of it

Comment: problem in drupal7 also; if you have any tutorial then give me link.

Answer (score 1):

Pdo driver for oracle does not work yet so d7 won't work until that is stable.  D6 is simply not supported.

If you need content from oracle I woul recommend using d7 with Postgres or MySQL and project forena to get data from oracle instance.